# wpftoolkit debugging error: Missing DataPointSeries.cs?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I used wpftoolkit to depict a chart but after depicting when I close the window visual studio suspends.

i debugged the program and it opens a window:

no source available .

and it then brings a window for openning DataPoints.cs:

C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataVisualization\Charting\DataPoint\DataPoint.cs

but there is no such file there!

what goes wrong??

[image: no source available]

Comment: VS tries to locate the corresponding source code from the WPFToolkit, but apparently you don't have it on your computer (or possibly it is not located in the expected search path).

Comment: you should really avoid using the DataVisualization toolkit. I'ts unstable, unreliable, and causes bad performance and memory leaks.

Comment: what kind of control can I use instead? an open source that is not oxyplot or DynamicDataDisplay because first gives errors in XAML and second has no docs...